# How to sync user's push channels without being able to query Installations

Tags: xcode, parse-platform

So, quite a straightforward questions, and one that should be simple but Parse doesn't allow querying of the Installation class.

Say I have a single user, and that user has an iPhone and an iPad.

When they register for a push notification channel, the channel is updated on their installation, the same for when they unregister.

My question is, how to I sync these subscriptions across the user's devices when I cannot query the Installation class?

Obviously, I can trigger a sync when the user uses each device, but if they unsubscribe from their iPhone, I don't want them to receive notifications for that channel on their iPad.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely query the PFInstallation class:

https://parse.com/docs/osx/api/Classes/PFInstallation.html#//api/name/query

I recommend you create a Cloud Code function to be called when a user unsubscribes. To be able to query for installations, you need to use the master key:

```
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
```

Comment: Sorry, I am referring to iOS.

Comment: As I said, I recommend you create a Cloud Code function. Cloud Code is available for all platforms, but is created with Javascript. Doing this in your app is not the way to go.

Comment: Just got around to testing this, and unfortunately even though you can query installations in CloudCode, the JavaScript SDK doesn't currently support adding and removing push channels!